# Questions regarding Sql count, join, percentage

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, cloths & shoes. what i am trying to do is extract data from cloths & shoes then count total before calculate percentage.
here is my code.

```
select cloths.id 
       shoes.id
       count(*) cloths.id, shoes.id as total,
       SUM(total) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(total)) OVER () AS Percentage
from cloths inner join shoes
on cloths.id = shoes.id 
order by cloths.id
group by cloths.id, shoes.id
```

however, i keep getting syntax error at or near "group". I tried different solutions, it won't work. I appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong order in the "ORDER BY" and "GROUP BY":

```
SELECT cloths.id 
       shoes.id
       COUNT(*) cloths.id, shoes.id as total,
       SUM(total) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(total)) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM cloths INNER JOIN shoes
  ON cloths.id = shoes.id 
GROUP BY cloths.id, shoes.id -- this one first
ORDER BY cloths.id; -- this one last
```